# Python Tkinter: How to get status message about menu action?

Tags: python, tkinter

The following produces a Tkinter text field with an example of a menu command (load text into text field).
There is supposed to be a Label functioning as a status line displaying what command has just been executed. So when clicking on "load", I want "file loaded" to be displayed.
I am struggling about getting `self.status` into `appmenu`. Reason: `app` must be called first (because of `self.text`), but in order to have `self.status` in `app`, `appmenu` should have been called first. No? Please help. 
Thanks in anticipation.

```
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog

class App (object):
  def __init__(self, master, status):
    self.status = status
    frame = Tkinter.Frame(master)
    frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    self.text_field(frame)
    self.status_line(frame)

  def status_line (self, frame):
    statusline = Tkinter.Label(frame, text = self.status)
    statusline.pack()

  def text_field(self, frame):
    self.text = Tkinter.Text(frame)
    self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

class App_Menu(object):
  def __init__(self, master, text, status):
    self.text = text
    self.master = master
    menubar = Tkinter.Menu(master)
    self.menuBar = Tkinter.Menu(master)
    master.config(menu=self.menuBar)
    self.fillMenuBar(text)

  def fillMenuBar(self, text):
    self.menuFile = Tkinter.Menu(self.menuBar, tearoff=False)
    self.menuFile.add_command(label="Open",command=self.load)
    self.menuBar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=self.menuFile)

  def load(self):
    self.file=tkFileDialog.askopenfile()
    self.text.delete(1.0, Tkinter.END)
    if self.file:
      self.text.insert(1.0,self.file.read())
      self.status = "file loaded"

root = Tkinter.Tk()
status = "status"
app = App(root, status)
appmenu = App_Menu(root, app.text, status)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `self.status = ...`, you are assigning a new value to the instance variable, but it does not change the text of the label. To do so, you can use a StringVar and the `set` method to change its value:

```
class App (object):
  # ...
  def status_line (self, frame):
    statusline = Tkinter.Label(frame, textvariable = self.status)
    statusline.pack()
  # ...

class App_Menu(object):
  def __init__(self, master, text, status):
    # ...
    self.status = status

  # ...
  def load(self):
    self.file=tkFileDialog.askopenfile()
    self.text.delete(1.0, Tkinter.END)
    if self.file:
      self.text.insert(1.0,self.file.read())
      self.status.set("file loaded")

root = Tkinter.Tk()
status = Tkinter.StringVar(root)
status.set("status")
```